# latex3 update breaks tikz library hobby

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

I'm using TeX Live 2015, after the latest `tlmgr update --all`,
I get the following Error message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \__msg_show_variable:Nnn undefined.
! 
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.185 ...riant:Nn \__msg_show_variable:Nnn { Nno }
```

This is caused by the tikz library hobby. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
Hallo Welt!
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: One to complain at the maintainer about :-) Using an internal function is clearly  not supported for `expl3`.

Comment: Fix available at https://github.com/loopspace/hobby though I fully expect it to be equally "unsupported" as I'm having difficulties figuring out how to achieve the same end without using "internal functions".  Fortunately, it's not a crucial part of the package and if all else fails, I'll just remove the bit that uses that function.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get it to work under TeX Live 2015, thus I'll be reverting to TeX Live 2014.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the package dependency of hobby includes L3 suite. A particular L3 update temporarily broke hobby which is fixed now.

Comment: I have the same problem even after using the new version of hobby in the @LoopSpace 's  comment !!.

Comment: Same here, updated all texlive packages today. I just installed texlive today and directly updated it, did not try if it worked before. Any help appreciated. I did not try the github version, just the one of texlive (rev. 34958 / 1.6)

Comment: You have to download the file hobby.dtx from https://github.com/loopspace/hobby, then perform `tex hobby.dtx`. The generated files have to be copied into the texlive tree, replacing the old ones.